# How to extract just the number from html?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I am trying to extract on the number from this html element:

```
<td bgcolor="green">
    <font color="white">
        "49.8 "
        <small>dBmV</small>
    </font>
</td>
```

How do only extract the 49.8 without getting the bBmV also?

I am able to use the xpath on  to return the all of 49.8 dbmv but when searching the xpath of just "49.8" I receive error

Error:

```
invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/p[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/font/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

I have tried:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/p[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/font").text
```

which returns 
49.8 dBmV

And then:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/p[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/font/text()").text
```

returns the exception above.

I just want the number 49.8 (which changes obviously).
i know i could extract the number later but im hoping there something I can use to just to get the details directly from the html, something a bit tidier

Comment: For this, when selenium methods fool me, I'm actually just splitting the html text for my needs using builtin funcs, but i don't know if you'd still want to do it with selenium or not

Comment: 49.8<space>dBmV? Is there a space in between?

Comment: in the results? yeah there is a space

Comment: Use the `.split()` and then get the 0th element from the list

Comment: `a = "49.8 dBmV"` `a.split()[0]`, Result --> `'49.8'`

Comment: Any way to just extract directly from the html rather than having to split after?

Comment: Can you provide the URL of that website?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is an internal corporate website

Comment: can you provide more HTML?

Comment: Can i search the element ignoring the /small part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the text **49.8** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* through `execute_script()` and *textContent*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@bgcolor='green']/font[@color='white']")).strip())
  ```
- Using *xpath* through `splitlines()` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@bgcolor='green']/font[@color='white']").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[1])
  ```

Comment: GOod one! did not think of `splitlines()`!

Comment: Thats done it! 
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@bgcolor='green']/font[@color='white']")).strip())

is working for me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first line and just get the number like this:

```
text_num = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/p[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/font").text
print(float(text_num.split()[0]))
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: I can do that but i would prefer to extract directly from the html, if its possible

Answer (score 1):

You can `replace` the extra text like this:

```
first_text = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/p[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/font").text
second_text = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/p[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/font/small").text
only_first_text = first_text.replace(second_text, '')
```

Comment: Hmm yeah that would work but still hoping to be able to extract the number directly without another line to delete the text. Can i search element ignoring the /small part?

Answer (score 0):

The `find_element_by_xpath` API in Selenium only supports returning elements, so eventhough it's possible in XPath to specify an expression that would return just the text that you're looking for it won't be possible in this case with XPath only.

Comment: The comment makes a lot of sense, thanks, but ive tried that line and still getting an error, although now it gives unable to locate:

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/p[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/font/text()[0]"}

I tried several variations as well, trying to make and work but getting no such element or invalid selector exceptions

Comment: @GlennDavies Sorry, I was looking at the Xpath without considering the selenium context properly. The `find_element_by_xpath` only supports returning elements, it won't work with Xpaths that return anything else. I will update my answer now.