# Extract text from Text Node using XPath

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, textnode

I am new to XPath and trying to capture the values "Time: " and "13:45" from the following HTML snippet. Any help or suggestion will be really useful. Thank you!

```
<div class="inner-box">
    <p class="inner-info-blk">
        <strong>Time: </strong>
        "13:45"
    </p>
</div>
```

I can access the label with in the `<strong>...</strong>` container with the pattern below but cannot figure out how to get the time value with in the `<p ...>` container.

Label xpath:

```
//div[@class="inner-box"]/p[@class="inner-info-blk"]/strong
```

Comment: If you are using selenium, you can get the info with this
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="inner-info-blk"]]).text

Answer (score 1):

Given the HTML:

```
<div class="inner-box">
    <p class="inner-info-blk">
        <strong>Time: </strong>
        "13:45"
    </p>
</div>
```

The time value i.e. **13:45** is a within a [Text Node_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007124/7429447) and the *lastChild* of it's parent `<p>`. So to extract the desired text you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath*, `execute_script()` and *textContent*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class="inner-box"]/p[@class="inner-info-blk"]")).strip())
  ```
- Using *xpath*, `get_attribute()` and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.inner-box > p.inner-info-blk").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[2])
  ```

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can also use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as follows:

Code Block:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = '''
<div class="inner-box">
    <p class="inner-info-blk">
        <strong>Time: </strong>
        "13:45"
    </p>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

last_text = soup.find("p", {"class": "inner-info-blk"}).contents[2]
print(last_text.strip())
```

Console Output:

```
"13:45"
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to extract just the number from html?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56681829/7429447)
- [Trying to get following element (text) without class tag etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70224307/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text()` to get the text from an element.

```py
from lxml import etree

html = '''
<div class="inner-box">
<p class="inner-info-blk">
    <strong>Time: </strong>
    "13:45"
</p>
'''

x = etree.HTML(html)
result = x.xpath('//div[@class="inner-box"]/p[@class="inner-info-blk"]/text()[2]') # get the text inside p
print(result[0].strip()) # since LXML return a list, you need to get the first one
```

And that would get the text from the `<p>` element.

**UPDATE:**
As @shailesh has mentioned, the Selenium locator would not evaluate XPath expression that returns a text; nor, to the best of my knowledge, there exists such a method in Selenium that will evaluate arbitrary XPath expression. But just to offer an alternative, you may also use a bit of JS here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    "file:///C:/Users/yubo/data/social/stackoverflow/6.10%20Selenium/example.html"
)
time = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH,
    './/div[@class="inner-box"]/p[@class="inner-info-blk"]',
)
print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent", time).strip()) # Same as @undetected selenium; a coincidence where we happened to write at the same time.
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you Yubo. Appreciate it, The code is itself works fine, But, I am getting this error "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'xpath'" when using in the loop where I extrac the value from all the elements. Previously I was trying: time = entry.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="inner-box"]/p[@class="inner-info-blk"]').text

Comment: @Yubo Ah, `return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent` it's purely _**plagiarized**_ content from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76448423/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the solution using split method, because Locators do not allow to use text() method with xpath. **Time:** in your example is a static and unique value which can split to get actual time value what you expect. I would recommend to first deal with xpath, if not found the solution try to resolve by logic. May be this can help you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.yourpage.html')
time = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//p")

print(time.text.split("Time:")[1])

driver.quit()
```

**O/P:**
"13:45"

This can be also relevant

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('file:///Users/shakava/Downloads/stackoverflow.html')
time = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//p")
arr = time.text.split(":")

START = 1
timeVal = ""

for index, item in enumerate(arr[START:], START):
    if index>1:
        timeVal+=":"

    timeVal+=item
    index+1

print(timeVal)
driver.quit()
```

**O/P:**
"13:45"