# Cannot extract span text content using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating python project which goal is to  extract some data from estate portal.
I work in python and I use selenium package. To find elements I use Xpath's .

Generally every works fine but when i try to extract text of span i encounter a problem.

span's html:

```
<span class="some-class">
    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.ty.org/1000/svg"  class="other-some-class">
        <path d="some-path" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd">
        </path>
    </svg> 
text to scrap
</span>
```

I extract this span using xpath .

```
my_obj = i.find_element(By.XPATH, './div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span'
```

I think it is correct because it returns selenium object and when i try to get class attribute using:

```
print('my_obj',my_obj.get_attribute('class'))
```

it returns correct class `some-class`

My problem is that's i cannot extract text of this span. I mean `text to scrap`.

I think i have tried  everything .

```
my_obj.text
my_obj.get_attribute('innetText')
my_obj.get_attribute('textContent')
my_obj.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

These obove doesnt't work.

Any Idea whats's I 'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Given the HTML:

```
<span class="some-class">
    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.ty.org/1000/svg"  class="other-some-class">
        <path d="some-path" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd">
        </path>
    </svg> 
    text to scrap
</span>
```

The text i.e. **text to scrap** is a within a [*Text Node*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76448423/7429447) and the *lastChild* of it's parent `<p>`. So to extract the desired text you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath*, `execute_script()` and *textContent*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class="some-class"]")).strip())
  ```
- Using *xpath*, `get_attribute()` and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.some-class").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[2])
  ```

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can also use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as follows:

Code Block:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = '''
<span class="some-class">
    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.ty.org/1000/svg"  class="other-some-class">
        <path d="some-path" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd">
        </path>
    </svg> 
    text to scrap
</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
last_text = soup.find("span", {"class": "some-class"}).contents[2]
print(last_text.strip())
```

Console Output:

```
text to scrap
```

---

### Another Alternative

As another alternative you can also use [lxml.etree](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html) as follows:

Code Block:

```
from lxml import etree

html_text = '''
<span class="some-class">
    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.ty.org/1000/svg"  class="other-some-class">
        <path d="some-path" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd">
        </path>
    </svg> 
    text to scrap
</span>
'''
x = etree.HTML(html)
result = x.xpath('//span[@class="some-class"]/text()[2]') # get the text inside span
print(result[0].strip()) # since LXML return a list, you need to get the first one
```

Console Output:

```
text to scrap
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to extract just the number from html?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56681829/7429447)
- [Trying to get following element (text) without class tag etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70224307/7429447)